# yii2 calculated 2 value in action create

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, yii2

This my action create in controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new User();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Database:**

```
tb_leave

id
id_employee <fk>
startdate
enddate
duration
leave_type //enum 'annual leave','medical check'

tb_employee
id
name
address
total_leave
```

The logic is // `if "total_leave" >= "duration" && leave_type = "Annual Leave"` then `total_leave - duration`. And the result insert to total_leave in `tb_employee`.

Can someone help me for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add beforeSave function to tb_leave model class like below and update total_leave value.

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {

        $user = User::find()->where(['id' => this->id_employee])->one();

        if($user->total_leave >= this->duration && this->leave_type = "annual Leave"){
            $user->total_leave = $user->total_leave - this->duration;
            $user->save();
        }

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

this function will trigger every time before saving tb_leave.

Comment: thx @irfan it's working for me. but I want add limit in this calculated. ex: total_leave="1" - duration"4", this result would be -3.. so i want limit the result until -1.. Do you have a solution?